# Update an antd RangePicker from outside the component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I see the `antd` RangePicker inputs are read-only. But, I need to update that using React state outside `antd` using a button to increment or decrement the date range.

here is the code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

import moment from 'moment-timezone';
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, DatePicker } from 'antd'

const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;


const defaultDateRange = [
  moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').startOf('isoWeek'),
  moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').endOf('isoWeek')
]

export default function App() {
  const [selectedPeriod, updatedSelectedPeriod] = useState(defaultDateRange)

  const findDateDiffDays = useCallback(() => {
    const [start, end] = selectedPeriod;
    return moment(end).diff(start, 'days')
  }, selectedPeriod)

  const changePeriod = useCallback((periodType) => () => {
    const [start, end] = selectedPeriod
    const days = findDateDiffDays()
    if(periodType === 'next') {
      updatedSelectedPeriod([start.add(days, 'days'), end.add(days, 'days')])
    } else if(periodType === 'prev') {
      updatedSelectedPeriod([start.subtract(days, 'days'), end.subtract(days, 'days')])
    }
  }, [selectedPeriod, updatedSelectedPeriod, findDateDiffDays])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button
        size="small"
        disabled={!selectedPeriod}
        onClick={changePeriod('prev')}
      >
        -1
      </Button>
      <RangePicker
        allowClear={false}
        bordered={false}
        onChange={updatedSelectedPeriod}
        value={selectedPeriod}
        defaultValue={selectedPeriod}
        suffixIcon={null}
        size='small'
      />
      <Button
        size="small"
        disabled={!selectedPeriod}
        onClick={changePeriod('next')}
      >
        +1
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I try to update the field using the range picker, there is no use. But I want to increment the date of the date picker using the button placed outside.

Codesandbox link to try out this here: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-grass-bz3dh?file=/src/App.js:0-1647

Answer (score 0):

`antd` inputs are checking object references to update its date values. Because of this, cloning the date range and updating the state fixed the above issue.

Previous Code:

```
const changePeriod = useCallback((periodType) => () => {
  const [start, end] = selectedPeriod
  const days = findDateDiffDays()
  if(periodType === 'next') {
    updatedSelectedPeriod([start.add(days, 'days'), end.add(days, 'days')])
  } else if(periodType === 'prev') {
    updatedSelectedPeriod([start.subtract(days, 'days'), end.subtract(days, 'days')])
  }
}, [selectedPeriod, updatedSelectedPeriod, findDateDiffDays])
```

Changed function:

```
const changePeriod = useCallback((periodType) => () => {
  const [start, end] = selectedPeriod
  const days = findDateDiffDays()
  if(periodType === 'next') {
    updatedSelectedPeriod([start.clone().add(days, 'days'), end.clone().add(days, 'days')])
  } else if(periodType === 'prev') {
    updatedSelectedPeriod([start.clone().subtract(days, 'days'), end.clone().subtract(days, 'days')])
  }
}, [selectedPeriod, updatedSelectedPeriod, findDateDiffDays])
```